# Basic CouchDB Local-to-Remote Replication

Tags: http, replication, couchdb, basic-authentication

I am playing around with CouchDB Replication and I'm wondering how to copy a local database of name "myDatabase" to a remote database on www.mySite.com that requires ssh access, and rename it to "myRemoteDatabase".  How do I do that?

I am able to login to both the *local* and *remote* servers and run:

`curl -X GET http://localhost:5984/`

...and it will show me the result, but when I am on my local computer and I run:

`curl -X GET http://my.ip.address:5984/`

... or even

`curl -X GET http://USER:PASSWORD@my.ip.address:5984/`

I get:

```
curl: (7) couldn't connect to host
```

What am I missing in this picture?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given the data you supplied, it can only be one thing.

You have configured CouchDB to listen on the localhost interface and no other.  I'm unfamiliar with how CouchDB is configured, but it will be some option about binding to `127.0.0.1` or (in an IPv6 world) `::1`.  Many configurations do this by default as it is fairly safe.  It will not allow access by any host other than localhost.

One possibility that I was thinking about is that the two machines have firewalls up that are not allowing connections from the outside world to port 5984.  But almost no firewall protects a computer from access from itself.  They can, but almost never do.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo vi /etc/couchdb/default.ini
```

Under [httpd], change

```
bind_address = 127.0.0.1
```

to that server's IP, then:

```
sudo service couchdb restart
```